# Edits not being counted towards reputation

Tags: support, bug

I recently noticed that the edits I have made are not being counted towards my reputation. Under my profile, the [Reputation tab](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/50259/agarza?tab=reputation) lists my last counted edit on December 21, 2023. But under the Activity > [Suggestions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/50259/agarza?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), I have numerous edits that have been approved.

Am I misunderstanding something or is there a glitch in the system?

Comment: is it possible you've earned 1000 pts via edits (I don't want to add all the points through 12 pages of rep)? https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation mentions +2 up to 1000

Comment: That must be it. I guess I am still asleep this morning. Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: There is a cap. Just not sure what is the limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You joined the exclusive [Gold Copy Editor Badge Club](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor) on Dec 25, 2023 (only 10 members so far).  The badge is given once you have edited 500 posts (that are approved).  There is a cap on how much reputation (+2 per edit) you can earn, [the limit is 500 edits accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116946/625056).  That's why you no longer earn reputation for your edits since then.

However, since your current reputation (1,918) is still under 2,000, your edits still need to be approved / rejected.  But you're close to automatic approval of edits, if you earn 82 more reputation by other means, such as getting a vote up on questions and answers.

**THANK YOU SO MUCH for improving the quality of questions and answers.**  I approved many of your edits and see how they are consistently within the policy, so no need for me to change anything almost all the time.

Comment: I appreciate the compliment. I just wish other users were more open to accepting the reason for the edits I make; there have been a few users who have rejected my edits and the reasons for them. It makes it a bit frustrating and I have limited my edits to mostly new users or those that I know have no qualms about my edits.

Comment: @agarza Yes, that can be frustrating.  I guess it's part of new user orientation that they need to remember that their posts are not truly their own, although the system has policies to retain the integrity of authorship *to the ideas*, not the wording / style / form of them.  By the way, I would welcome a meta post from you describing your edit patterns so others can follow you, especially for accessibility.  If there is not already an existing meta question about C.SE specific stylistic guidelines (that also talks about best practice for Bible verses, for example) feel free to create one.

Comment: I had asked on Meta Stack Exchange about accessibility and eventually, a consolidated post was made (see [How do I write an accessible Stack Exchange post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394687/how-do-i-write-an-accessible-stack-exchange-post)).

Comment: @agarza anybody who rejects your edits never met the "active reader" people on the other sites who edit answers instead of reading them. Those people infuriate me, your intention and acts are pure - I'll almost always favor going with your changes to posts over the originals.  In any case it's a good explanation of how the site works to newbies and the revelation that "your posts are not your own" needs to be understood by all who participate here

Comment: @agarza Wow, quite a long and detailed guideline.  I guess it's a required reading for me who posts quite a lot in SE.